C# MAUI Событие GraphicsView StartInteraction не работает
По нажатию на GraphicsView должно происходить событие и вызываться метод tap, однако отладчик никак не реагирует на нажатия в этой области. И label не меняет своего значения.
XAML:
<Label 
    x:Name="lb"
    Text="You touch nothing"/>

<GraphicsView
    x:Name="tralala"
    StartInteraction="tap"/>

CS:
private void tap(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    lb.Text = "You touch my tralala"
}


Здесь мало специалистов по MAUI, возможно стоит продублировать вопрос на английском StackOverflow.

Нужно установить - Heightrequest и Widthrequest в параметрах GraphicsView, т.к. по умолчанию они равны -1.
